# Tkinter dynamic label that displays the result of an equation?

Tags: python, tkinter

Apologies if this has been solved somewhere else. I couldn't find any solutions that weren't based on running a function/clicking a button.

I have two columns of entry slots where slot 1 - slot 2 = outcome
on column 3, I'd like to display the outcome live. Is this possible?

Displaying textvariable in a label seems dynamic enough but it doesn't seem to work if it's something being changed in the moment (unless I'm changing one variable and displaying that one variable in another label)

Right now, I just have it **set** which I'm aware only runs on start

[image: preview]

```
t1_in = IntVar(root, value=0)
t1_out = IntVar(root, value=0)

total1 = IntVar(root, value=0)
total1.set(t1_in.get() - t1_out.get())

in1 = Entry(root, width=10,textvariable=t1_in).grid(row=4, column=in_col)
out1 = Entry(root, width=10,textvariable=t1_out).grid(row=4, column=out_col)

t1 = Label(root, textvariable=total1, font=30).grid(row=4, column=t_col)
```

Is there any way to directly display total1 showing **t1_in - t1_out** dynamically as the user types in the text field new values?

Comment: You mean an automatic result?

Comment: Yeah, that's what dynamic means.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with tracing, and an intermediate variable that holds the end result. There may be a better way to do this, but something like this works well:

```py
t1_in = IntVar(root, value=0)
t1_out = IntVar(root, value=0)

total1 = IntVar(root, value=0)


in1 = Entry(root, width=10,textvariable=t1_in).grid(row=4, column=in_col)
out1 = Entry(root, width=10,textvariable=t1_out).grid(row=4, column=out_col)

def dynamic_total(var, index, mode):
    total1.set(t1_in.get() - t1_out.get())

t1_in.trace_add('write', dynamic_total)
t1_out.trace_add('write', dynamic_total)

t1 = Label(root, textvariable=total1, font=30).grid(row=4, column=t_col)
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't heard of tracing